# In Magento 2, how can I get all orders (particularly total amounts of orders) without using objectManager, by using REST methods

Tags: magento2

I am a complete Magento 2 noob, I need to get all order amounts without going into `objectManager`, how can I do this using REST methods? So, I need to traverse ALL orders using REST service of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Tis curl call will return all orders:
$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/elettrocity/index.php/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria");